# Redmine Error. C:\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, redmine, helicontech

Error

Helicon Zoo module has caught up an error. Please see the details below.

Worker Status

```
Worker process shut down.The worker process shut down unexpectedly.         Possible causes are errors in the application, missing dependencies or insufficient file permissions.Please read application specific errors and logs for more information.
```

Windows error
    The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (ERROR CODE: 995)

Internal module error
     message: ZooApplication I/O Error.
    type: ZooException
    file: Job.cpp
    line: 276
    version: 2.0.77.328

STDERR

```
C:\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb (LoadError)
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have Ruby installed or have it installed to the wrong location or of wrong version. Make sure Ruby is located in C:\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe